# how can insert the value of lst[i] in the command

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a python script which will take input from text file and run an external command.

```
 import os
 with open('media.txt') as f:
 lst = [i.strip() for i in f]
 length=len(lst)
 print(length)
  i=length
 for x in range(i):
 os.system('mediacontent.exe -m lst[i]')
 print(lst[i])
 i+=1
```

Please help me to insert the value of lst[i] in the command.

The content of file media.txt is as below:

> *1234
>   *6753
>   *9897
>   *5656

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
 os.system('mediacontent.exe -m %s'%lst[i])
```

You can check out [this link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) if you want to learn more

Comment: The link you provided describes new-style formatting, but your example shows old-style formatting; there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
foo = 10
"foo is {}".format(foo)
```